# Website unavailable to me

Tags: website

I can no longer connect to the website mytraveline.mobi which I have always used to give me live bus times at my nearest stop. When I try to ping the site, I get no returns.

I have contacted the people who run it but they don't know why either.

I have emailed the link I use to other people and it all works for them.

Anybody got any idea what I can do?!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you don't have the subdomain in the URL you are giving

You need to start the URL with `www` (which is the subdomain)

An example

By URL, http://superuser.com is different to http://www.superuser.com, and could actually point to different servers and serve totally different content (usually it makes sense to point to the same location).

Most people assume a website starts with `www.` and some assume it doesn't need `www.` - Neither are actually true. Convention suggests we should always have `www.` and ideally always accept when no subdomain is present (although I appreciate there are reasons not for things like SSL issues and SEO issues etc).

I also emailed that company to inform them (in case they decide to react to it)

In your post you wrote `mytraveline.mobi` which is what I *assume* is the URL you're trying to reach. Currently mytraveline.mobi shows an IIS page, where as www.mytraveline.mobi shows the website as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, you can use a check website like [Down For Everyone Or Just Me](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/) in order to see if the problem is likely unique to you or if others are experiencing it as well.

Comment: Thank you, I just used it and it is definitely down for Just Me!

Comment: OP has already stated that others can access it